# Logging error not returning name of all tables

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to execute multiple inserts and for errors I would need to have schema name and table name.

My example:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
cur.execute(sql)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(iter(cur), columns=[x[0] for x in cur.description])
my_dict = dict()

for i in df['col1'].unique().tolist():

    df_x = df[df['col1'] == i]
    my_dict[i] = df_x['col_table'].tolist()
    
 sql_list = []
 for schema, tables in my_dict.items():
    for table in tables:
    
        sql_list.append(f"INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} SELECT * FROM {schema}.{table} where col2 = 1;" )
        try:
            sql = 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE %s'
            cur.executemany(sql, sql_list)
        except: snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
                
            logging.error(f"Inserting in {schema}.{table}: {e}")

conn.close()
```

Logging error is returning only one table name for each insert.

Comment: @9769953 yes, my mistake while I was editing my code. But this not the issue.

Comment: @9769953 in my sql_list I am testing tables that have errors and I know that because I checked while executing sql inserts in db.

Comment: @9769953 I'm using cur.executemany() with some other lists of tables and it's executing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248943/discussion-between-my80-and-9769953).

Comment: @9769953 I expect to get error with info error and schema and table name.
So I shoud use this instead logging.error("Inserting in %s.%s: %s", schema, table, e)
or it shoud be logging.error("Inserting in %s.%s: %s", {schema}, {table}, e)

Comment: @9769953 could you give me an exaple (code).

Comment: @9769953 in my dictionary my_dict I have schema names as keys with list of tables. I'm iterating dictionary in order to create list with multiple inserts.

Comment: @9769953 so I expect logger to give me output what error while inserting and which schema and table. So error ...insert into schema ....table

Comment: @9769953 shoud I replace sql_list.append(...  with query = f"INSERT... and jusy use cur.execute()

Comment: @9769953 I didn't understand your comment: "Another side note: to me, your double loop logic with the insert seems flawed; or at least very odd: you insert something into table 1, then into table 1 and 2, then into table 1, 2 and 3, then into tables 1, 2, 3 and 4, and so on. Is that indeed the intention? " I'm itereting dictionary to get multiple inserts for schema and table. In dictionary I have keys as schemas so schema TEST has list with tables etc. my output in the list is insert into test.table001...insert into test.table002...